# Random Image selector from folder

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, undefined

I'm a student working on an art project in which I select one of 500 created images to show up on a webpage. I'm very new to coding and only really understand html and css, with very small amount of knowledge in JavaScript. I'm stuck in getting the images to show up, when I inspect it gives me an error saying: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND $selected_image}< I'm not really sure what to do with this, I hope someone would like to help me with this.

Thankyou :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/main.css">
        <!-- <link rel="JavaScript" href="script.js"> -->
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta content='IE=edge,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
        <title>Mother</title>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="inner_container">
                <img id="image_shower"/>
            </div>
            <div id="button_container">
                <button onclick="get_random_image()"></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            image_array = [
                'Lilith10.png',
                'Lilith11.png',
                'Lilith12.png',
                'Lilith13.png',
                'Lilith14.png']

            function get_random_image(){
                random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * image_array.lenght);
                selected_image = image_array[random_index]
                document.getElementById('image_shower').src = './images/$selected_image}'}

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's `length`, not `lenght`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript template strings are written with oblique quotes, and variables inside it must have brackets around them (you only had the closing one):

```js
document.getElementById('image_shower').src = `./images/${selected_image}`;
```

EDIT

Even if in the present case this won't stop your code from working (unless you activate "strict mode"), I also recommend that you use the appropriate keywords to declare your variables.

```js
const image_array = [
  'Lilith10.png',
  'Lilith11.png',
  'Lilith12.png',
  'Lilith13.png',
  'Lilith14.png'
];

function get_random_image() {
  const random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * image_array.length);
  const selected_image = image_array[random_index];
  document.getElementById('image_shower').src = `./images/${selected_image}`;
}
```

Comment: I forgot the opening bracket there looked over it tens of times. I need to use the oblique quotes to close them off. Also  using appropriate keywords to declare my variables. Thankyou for the help :)